# How do I build and run api-platform image to a production docker container?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, api-platform.com

I have followed the api-platform tutorial and successfully built and started the application using Docker on my `localhost` machine.

I have a production server running Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS, and a newly installed  Docker version 18.06.1-ce.

How would I build this code on my local machine and run it on the Docker server?

I have also looked at the [Deploying API Platform Applications documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/deployment) but I am not sure how to use this.

I am struggling to understand how to build api-platform from my localhost to the server

Answer (score 1):

this is docker-compose.yml file try this please docker-compose up -d

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  php:
    image: ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/php
    build:
      context: ./api
      target: api_platform_php
      cache_from:
        - ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/php
        - ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/nginx
        - ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/varnish
    depends_on:
      - db
    # Comment out these volumes in production
    volumes:
      - ./api:/srv/api:rw,cached
      # If you develop on Linux, uncomment the following line to use a bind-mounted host directory instead
      # - ./api/var:/srv/api/var:rw

  api:
    image: ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/nginx
    build:
      context: ./api
      target: api_platform_nginx
      cache_from:
        - ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/php
        - ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/nginx
        - ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/varnish
    depends_on:
      - php
    # Comment out this volume in production
    volumes:
      - ./api/public:/srv/api/public:ro
    ports:
      - "8080:80"

  cache-proxy:
    image: ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/varnish
    build:
      context: ./api
      target: api_platform_varnish
      cache_from:
        - ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/php
        - ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/nginx
        - ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/varnish
    depends_on:
      - api
    volumes:
      - ./api/docker/varnish/conf:/usr/local/etc/varnish:ro
    tmpfs:
      - /usr/local/var/varnish:exec
    ports:
      - "8081:80"

  db:
    # In production, you may want to use a managed database service
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=api
      - POSTGRES_USER=api-platform
      # You should definitely change the password in production
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=!ChangeMe!
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
      # You may use a bind-mounted host directory instead, so that it is harder to accidentally remove the volume and lose all your data!
      # - ./docker/db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  client:
    # Use a static website hosting service in production
    # See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment
    image: ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/client
    build:
      context: ./client
      cache_from:
        - ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/client
    env_file:
      - ./client/.env
    volumes:
      - ./client:/usr/src/client:rw,cached
      - /usr/src/client/node_modules
    ports:
      - "80:3000"

  admin:
    # Use a static website hosting service in production
    # See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment
    image: ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/admin
    build:
      context: ./admin
      cache_from:
        - ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/admin
    volumes:
      - ./admin:/usr/src/admin:rw,cached
      - /usr/src/admin/node_modules
    ports:
      - "81:3000"

  h2-proxy:
    # Don't use this proxy in prod
    build:
      context: ./h2-proxy
    depends_on:
      - client
      - admin
      - api
      - cache-proxy
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "444:444"
      - "8443:8443"
      - "8444:8444"

volumes:
  db-data: {}
```